# How to test two different classes with a same name with karma test-runner during a single run?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

My problem lies in the next. I have a javascript application. It utilises the so called module pattern. That is I have multiple js files (one for each class) and during the build process all these files are put to a single file and wrapped in the IIFE. So in my karma config file I specify

```
files: ['src/**/*.js', 'tests/**/*.js']
```

The problem arises because I need to use several "modules" in this app. Here is the example of the tree structure of the code:

```
    ├── karma_unit.conf.js
├── src
│   ├── Bar
│   │   └── module.js
│   └── Foo
│       └── module.js
└── tests
    └── unit
        ├── Bar
        │   └── test.js
        └── Foo
            └── test.js
```

So I have two `Module` classes at the same time. This is not the problem with the "built" code. But for the unit tests this is the problem, because this is the name conflict.

I know that I can have different config files for each such a module and run tests several times (one per a single config file), but this is very undesirable.

Also I supposed that files are executed with respect to their inclusion order, so I tried to write in the config file:

```
files: [
    'src/Foo/*.js',
    'tests/Foo/*.js',
    'src/Bar/*.js',
    'tests/Bar/*.js',
]
```

But this did not help.

So my question is: how can I circumvent this situation when I'm forced to have several javascript classes with the same name in a single project without running tests several times or renaming these classes?

My appreciation in advance.

Comment: If you are using requirejs for implementing `module pattern` in your project, you might find this interesting: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html

Comment: @Nitin... , finally I've found time to tackle this, thank you for your suggestion it is almost exactly what I need. Would you post an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reference link that details a solution for your query:

http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html